# create "expand text" button for grid view column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Need help to create a button or link button to expand text in grid view column

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AcceptServerGroups" HeaderText="Accepted Server Group"
    ItemStyle-Width="200px" meta:resourcekey="BoundFieldResource3">
    <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: I think for what you are trying to do you need to look at using `ItemTemplate`

Comment: is this possible using java script? I just need provide option for user to expand column text an by default text should be collapsed.